# .map On an array of objects, with a sub-object within an object: [ {}, { { { } } }, { } ]

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, javascript-objects

Currently working on mapping out some template cards with some parsed json, yet I noticed I'm not returning / accessing the data returned from my fetch call properly within the .map method.

Here is a snippet of the json data:

```
const dataArr = [
{
id: 1,
name: "Leanne Graham",
username: "Bret",
email: "Sincere@april.biz",
   address: {
     street: "Kulas Light",
     suite: "Apt. 556",
     city: "Gwenborough",
     zipcode: "92998-3874",
     geo: {
     lat: "-37.3159",
     lng: "81.1496"
     }
   },
phone: "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
website: "hildegard.org",
company: {
name: "Romaguera-Crona",
catchPhrase: "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
bs: "harness real-time e-markets"
}
},
{
id: 2,
name: "Ervin Howell",
username: "Antonette",
email: "Shanna@melissa.tv",
address: {
street: "Victor Plains",
suite: "Suite 879",
city: "Wisokyburgh",
zipcode: "90566-7771",
geo: {
lat: "-43.9509",
lng: "-34.4618"
}
},
phone: "010-692-6593 x09125",
website: "anastasia.net",
company: {
name: "Deckow-Crist",
catchPhrase: "Proactive didactic contingency",
bs: "synergize scalable supply-chains"
}
},
```

I'm attempting to use this with the following template:

```
const renderUser = (user, index) => {
        return(
            <div className="user-card" key={"user-" + index}>
            <header>
                <h2>{user.name}</h2>
            </header>
            <section className="company-info">
                <p><b>Contact:</b>{user.email}</p>
                <p><b>Works for:</b>{user.company}</p>
                <p><b>Company creed:</b>{user.company}</p>
            </section>
            <footer>
                <button className="load-posts">POSTS BY {user.username}</button>
                <button className="load-albums">ALBUMS BY {user.username}</button> 
            </footer>
        </div>
        )
    };
```

Currently I've tried:

```
dataArr.map(renderUser);
```

Though to no avail.

Where might I be going wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help - been stuck on this for 10 hours at least [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5uTf.png)

Comment: "yet I noticed I'm not returning / accessing..." and how did you notice? How do you know it's not working? Where is the actual rendering code?

Comment: @DennisVash So the raw json can be accessed at the following endpoint: 

[link](https://jsonplace-univclone.herokuapp.com/users) _italic_ **bold**

As for the confirmation, I receive the following error when attempting to run with the posted snippet:

`Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, catchPhrase, bs}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

I've tried a normal .map by only rendering one layer of nested object E.g. [ {}, {} ]. And that renders just fine

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, it would help a lot if you add at least a screenshot of your error, which I assume you encountered due to the code you have shared.

As for the code, one thing I noticed is that you are using the value of `{user.company}` twice, which in the `dataArr` is an object. In order for this to work, you will need to specify which one of the three props in `user.company` you will use in those two instances:

```
company: {
  name: "Romaguera-Crona",
  catchPhrase: "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
  bs: "harness real-time e-markets",
},
```

The instances I'm talking about:

```
<p><b>Works for:</b>{user.company}</p>
<p><b>Company creed:</b>{user.company}</p>
```

Example of a proper implementation:

```
<p><b>Works for:</b>{user.company.name}</p>
<p><b>Company creed:</b>{user.company.catchPhrase}</p>
```

(didn't know what you wanted to display for 'Company creed')

Comment: Ahh, wasn't aware I could add an image.

First time actually asking for help on stackOverflow - need to learn how to use.

Anyhow - I uploaded an error image, and indented the json for some clarity.

As for the value of {user.company}, I did that intentionally for now just to see if I could return any sort of data when I took out some of the nested objects.

Thanks for the proper implementation - I'll give that a go.

Comment: Actually, That fixed it completely!

Thanks for the help  - was about ready to toss my macbook lol.

Now I just need to figure out why my fetch call / react hooks aren't working properly 

Comment: @tpadilla10117 Hello, glad this helped, if this was the answer you were looking for, please mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Credit @KevinHaxhi user:16532250:

```
company: {
  name: "Romaguera-Crona",
  catchPhrase: "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
  bs: "harness real-time e-markets",
},
```

```
<p><b>Works for:</b>{user.company}</p>
<p><b>Company creed:</b>{user.company}</p>
```

Example of a proper implementation:

```
<p><b>Works for:</b>{user.company.name}</p>
<p><b>Company creed:</b>{user.company.catchPhrase}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can observe from the information provided above that you want to render all users.
I can see that in the given JSON data, "company" property is an object within object and contains properties. The error you are receiving is due to that. Because Object literals won't work as a React component child. Rather you need to access it's specific property that you are looking for.
Here is a simpler way to solve the above problem.

Create a parent component that receives renderUser component. Map the dataArr and pass the specific properties you want to use through props.

```
    const Parent=()=>{

   return(
       <div>
         {dataArr.map((user)=> 
    
        <Renderuser key={user.id}
                    name={user.name}
                    email={user.email}
                    company={user.company}
                    username={user.username}
             /> 
           )}
      </div>
   )
}
```

Call the props in the renderUser.Also, the React components' name should start with capital letter. So, you might want to change that too.

```
    const Renderuser = ({name, email, company, username}) => {


   return(
         <div className="user-card" >
         <header>
             <h2>Name: {name}</h2>
         </header>
         <section className="company-info">
           <p><b>Contact:</b>{email}</p>
           <p><b>Works for:</b>{company.name}</p>
           <p><b>Company creed:</b>{company.name}</p>
         </section>
       <footer>
         <button className="load-posts">POSTS BY : {username}</button>
         <button className="load-albums">ALBUMS BY : {username}</button> 
      </footer>
    </div>
  )
};
```

Please notice that I have used "company.name" as company is another object within the object. So, might want to iterate a particular property of the same by accessing it using dot notation.

This won't give you error.